# Hystrix dashboard stucks on loading screen

Tags: hystrix

I have Hystrix dashboard running on localhost:8988/hystrix and I want to monitor a request between OrderService and ProductService . The endpoint "hystrix.stream" is already registered and the hystrix dashboard stucks on loading without any results.

This is the service client to call Product Service which I want to monitor:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceClient {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public ProductServiceClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getDefaultProductById")
    public Optional<ProductDto> getProductById(Long productId) {
        ResponseEntity<ProductDto> productResponse = restTemplate
                .getForEntity("http://product-service/api/product/{id}",
                        ProductDto.class,
                        productId);
        if (productResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(productResponse.getBody());
        } else {
            log.error("Unable to get product with ID: " + productId
                    + ", StatusCode: " + productResponse.getStatusCode());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    Optional<ProductDto> getDefaultProductById(String productId) {
            log.info("Returning default ProductById for product Id: " + productId);
        ProductDto productDto = new ProductDto();
        productDto.setId(productId);
        productDto.setName("UNKNOWN");
        productDto.setDescription("NONE");
        return Optional.ofNullable(productDto);
    }
}
```

I added the @EnableCircuitBreaker annotation to the main class and I use these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I solved this problem. In fact, after I added hystrix starter dependency to the client microservice and enabling **hystrix.stream** endpoint in _application.properties_ like this: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` I didn"t make any call to the controller using a method annotaded with `@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallbackMethodName")` Imported from hystrix janica dependecy.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Issue

In my case, the error occurs after upgrade spring-cloud to `Hoxton.SR6`.

In browser console, get following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function

which seems to be a jquery version issue.

---

### Solution

Downgrade spring-cloud version to `Hoxton.SR4`,  then the error is gone.

So, you might need to check your browser's console output to see whether there are errors.

---

### Tips

- Another possible reason is that you didn't access your application's api which is marked by `@HystrixCommand` yet.
  In that case, make a call to the api, then the dashboard would show the charts.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending some requests by calling the controller.
If there are no requests then the dashboard will keep loading.